# Find the type of singularity of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{ C}\to \mathbb{ C}$  be a holomorphic function such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a countable and discrete set without accumulation point.   Find the type of singularity of $f$ at $\infty$.
I proved that $f$ can’t have a removable singularly because for Liouville theorem f have to be constant but I don’t know how to prove that $f$ have a pole or an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: The singularity at $\infty$ is isolated, since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, it is either removable, pole, or essential. If it were removable, then $f$ would be bounded near $\infty$ and therefore bounded everywhere. This would make it constant, and therefore equal to $0$. Therefore $f^{-1}(0)$ would be $\mathbb{C}$, which has many accumulation points. So, not removable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already excluded the possibility of a removable singularity.

If $f$ has a pole at $\infty$ then $|f(z)| > 1$ for sufficiently large $|z|$, i.e. all zeros of $f$ are located in some (compact) disk, so that $f^{-1}(0)$ is finite.

Therefore, if  $f^{-1}(0)$ is countable infinite, the singularity must be essential.